# Removing blank space in columns in pipe delimited file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an issue where I need to remove blank spaces in columns 3 and 4 which may or may not exist in a pipe delimited text file using powershell.

The input file looks like this :

```
COLMABQ1|02112017|001000 08248|BQ|Name|
COLMABP1|02112017|00100009693|B P|Name|
COLAL3|02112017|001000 12032|C D|Name|
COLMAAO|02112017|00100014915|AO|Name|
COLAL1H|02112017|00100 017939|C D|Name|
```

I need the output file to look like this :

```
COLMABQ1|02112017|00100008248|BQ|Name|
COLMABP1|02112017|00100009693|BP|Name|
COLAL3|02112017|00100012032|CD|Name|
COLMAAO|02112017|00100014915|AO|Name|
COLAL1H|02112017|00100017939|CD|Name|
```

The nearest I have come to solving it so far is converting the file to a .csv file, replacing every | with a ",", running the code below against columns 3 & 4 then changing all the "," back to |

```
$headers = 1..5|%{"H{0}" -f $_}
$Csv = Import-Csv $infile -Header $Headers
$Csv|ft -auto

ForEach ($Row in $Csv) {
 $Row.H3 = $Row.H3 -Replace ' '
}
$CSV | ConvertTo-CSV -NoType | Select -Skip 1 | Set-Content $outfile
```

Even this doesn't work exactly as I'd like and I'm convinced there must be a far easier way to do this...but 2 day's worth of Googling seems to suggest otherwise!

Any help anyone can give with this would be gratefully received as it's driving me insane.

Comment: _Even this doesn't work exactly as I'd like_ What does that mean? _How_ is it not working. Can you show the output from that? I can see some issues but I would like to suggest how to make this work as well. Namely the quoting might be undesired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```
Get-Content $infile |
 ForEach-Object {
    $parts = $_.split("|")
    $parts[2] = $parts[2].replace(" ","")
    $parts[3] = $parts[3].replace(" ","")
    $parts -join "|"
 } | Add-Content $Outfile
```

Comment: This works nicely for the conversion to csv & back etc

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Vincent imp\Test\Test.txt') -replace '(^.*\|.*\|.*) (.*\|.*\|.*\|)','$1$2' -replace '(^.*\|.*\|.*\|.*) (.*\|.*\|)','$1$2'

COLMABQ1|02112017|00100008248|BQ|Name|    
COLMABP1|02112017|00100009693|BP|Name|    
COLAL3|02112017|00100012032|CD|Name|    
COLMAAO|02112017|00100014915|AO|Name|    
COLAL1H|02112017|00100017939|CD|Name|
```

Comment: At first glance that looks like a painful way to just `-replace '\s'` which is what I effectively think this is doing. Also that could remove space where they were not meant to since the OP specified columns

Comment: That's better. While this satisfies the sample data this would not work if multiple or multiple non consecutive spaces were present.

Answer (score 0):

If only columns 3 & 4 have blank spaces :

`(Get-Content $infile) -replace '\s+' | Set-Content $infile`

Comment: That could remove space where they were not meant to since the OP specified _columns_

Comment: I was editing my answer to ask if blank spaces were always present in columns 3 or 4 or others columns too as in the example there's no space in columns 1 & 2

Comment: There may legitimately be spaces in the other columns. It's only columns 3 & 4 that definitely can't contain a space.

Comment: In a unix situation I'd use the following code to solve this :                            awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub(" ","",$3); gsub(" ","",$4)} 1' infile > outfile

Comment: I'm looking for a powershell version of this really, if such a thing exists?